Fly-to on svg image in javascript
First, I'm totally new to Javascript. I have some training (not that much) in html & css.
I have created an svg image of a piece of world map that I have illustrated myself and incorporated into my code. I want that by clicking a button, which I already have, the user can fly to a point on that image. Ideally like you fly to a point on the map on Google Maps or other map app.
I have the ID and coordinates of the point and I entered it in my java script as a "fly-to" with the ID. After all, I thought java script can see the separate layers and elements on the svg and thus fly to them. But I can't manage to fly to the point. Is my code of the "Fly-to" maybe wrong? Or does java script not recognise the elements of my svg? Or am I doing something else wrong? Or is flying impossible anyway?
A plan B would be to scroll and zoom to the point.  But I can't manage that either.
button:
<button id="fly-button" onclick="flyTo('Cameroon', 4)">Fly to Location</button>

js:
Fly to Location
function flyTo(id, scale) {
const svg = document.getElementById('Carolekaart');
if (svg) {
    console.log(svg);
    
    const targetX = 861.5763; 
    const targetY = 2766.9559; 

    
    const { x, y, width, height } = svg.viewBox.baseVal;
    console.log(x, y, width, height);

    
    const newWidth = width * scale;
    const newHeight = height * scale;
    const newX = targetX - newWidth / 2;
    const newY = targetY - newHeight / 2;
    console.log(newX, newY, newWidth, newHeight);

   
     svg.setAttribute("viewBox", 0, 1250, 1000, 1000);
}

}

Can you add your code so we can better understand the source of the problem?
